# How to connect to mysql remotely via SSH tunnel without password

Tags: ssh, mysql, remote, ssh-tunneling

On the server, I've got it set up, that the root doesn't need to enter password in order to use mysql (credentials are in ~/.mylogin.cnf). Now I want to connect to the mysql remotely via SSH tunnel and I'm expecting that i won't need to enter the password.

```
# open the tunnel (I'm using local port 3305 because 3306 is already taken for some reason)
ssh server -L 3305:127.0.0.1:3306 -N

# now try to connect
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3305 -u root
```

But this doesn't work. Error says: *ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you looking to do this to encrypt the data? If that is the case, Mysql/Mariadb has built in encryption that can be configured

Answer (score 2):

You've set up your mysql credentials on a **remote server** and you're running the mysql client **locally**.

Please set up an instance of mysql in ~/.mylogin.cnf for localhost at port 3305.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add -p at the end of the command to get a password prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you can open an ssh connection as root? Some Linux distributions restrict root ssh access by default. Check the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file  for the lines

```
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
```